# Hide admin toolbar based on a query string

Tags: admin, admin-bar

As far as I know the showing and hiding of the admin toolbar on the front-end is a global setting, which applies to any page containing `wp_footer()`.

I want to have more specific control over the visibility admin bar—specifically, to be able to hide it based on a URL query string, such as (e.g., `?hidetoolbar` at the end of a URL).

I know that I can hide the toolbar from a specific **template file** by adding this to the top:

```
     add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

What hook would I use to apply the filter conditionally in **functions.php**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to just add the filter inside of a conditional:

```
<?php if ($_GET['hidetoolbar']) 
{
    add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
}
?>
```

or, since conditionally adding action handlers and filters is sometimes frowned upon, you could add your own function as a filter and then put your conditional inside that:

```
<?php 
function my_manage_toolbar()
{
    if ($_GET['hidetoolbar']) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
add_filter('show_admin_bar', 'my_manage_toolbar');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in your functions.php file :

```
if (isset($_GET['hidetoolbar'])) {
    add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code for PHP7:

This will only act on non-admin pages, and will respect whatever status the admin bar was before checking. It also will not output any warnings in the log.

```
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', function( $show ) {
    if (
        ! is_admin() &&
        isset( $_GET['hidetoolbar'] )
    ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $show;
});
```

Comment: And what is the improvement over the existing answer?

Comment: @fuxia • Smaller, more maintainable code. • Will only act on non-admin pages (faster) • will not create an error in the log when the feature is not used (which will be most of the time) • will respect the settings of other filters that also adjust the output